# Firefox add-on to load webpage without network access

Tags: firefox-addon, postmessage

I'm wondering if Firefox can indicate that a webpage should be loaded but without network access (at least beyond its own directory). The purpose is to allow a file to conduct `postMessage` communications with a privileged add-on, but without there being any privacy concerns.

Comment: Where would that webpage come from? file:, chrome: or something like that. Or do you want a regular web-page not to (dynamically) load additional scripts?

Comment: The webpage would come from file:. And right, not to dynamically load additional scripts or even redirect to http, insert images in http, etc.--i.e., anything that could be used to pass on data obtained by the file's postMessage communications with my add-on back to a server.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'd think messing around with the `nsIPrincipal` attached to the document might work, or messing around with `nsIContentPolicy`... But I don't have an answer off the top of my head to that.